# How to discretize a variable with only 2 distinct values?

Tags: r, discretization

I am trying to discretize the variable- DEATH, into two bins. 
DEATH can only be a value of 0 or 1
The command I am using is as follows:

to convert Death to a factor variable using unsupervised discretization with equal frequency binning

```
burn$DEATH<-discretize(burn$DEATH, method="interval", breaks=2)
summary(burn$DEATH)
```

However, my output is the entire range of values. I would like to show the individual count for 0 and 1.

My current output:

```
summary(burn$DEATH)

[0,1] 
 1000
```

I think the user specified  method would be the solution but when I tried this, I received an error stating that 'x must be numeric'

```
burn$FACILITY <- discretize(burn$FACILITY, method="fixed", breaks=c(-Inf,0, 1, Inf))
```

Additional note: This is for a class so I'm assuming they wouldn't want us to use a method that we haven't discussed yet. I'd prefer to use a discretization method if possible! Someone suggested I use the factor() command, but how do I see the summary statistics with the levels if I do this?

Comment: Why not just use `factor(burn$DEATH)`?

Comment: `table(burn$DEATH)` ?

Comment: Assuming it is a factor, summary(burn$DEATH) will also work.